# React JS mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props

Several of my colleagues are spreading the part of the state in mapStateToProps.

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state = {}) =>
  ({
    addUserForm: { ...state.addUser.addUserForm },
    addUserLabels: { ...state.addUser.addUserLabels }
  });
```

Is it OK to do it? It duplicates the part of the state. And when actual Redux state changes the component won't get re rendered. Right? 
Correct me if I am wrong please.

Answer (score 1):

Because the spread is using `state` that is passed into `mapStateToProps` the component will still re-render when the state changes. I am not sure what is gained by the use of this spread syntax. Looks to achieve exactly the same thing as:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state = {}) =>
  ({
    addUserForm: state.addUser.addUserForm,
    addUserLabels: state.addUser.addUserLabels
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Appreciate the fast response.